# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm doing a React JS Course. I want to render the day and date by using **props** and **toLocaleString** method. But the app just crashes. Here's my code

```
 function ExpenseDate(props) {
  const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  const year = props.date.getFullYear();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{month}</div>
      <div>{year}</div>
      <div>{day}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseDate;
```

When I export & use that component & refresh the server. The server shows this:
[Undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYwwb.png)

Please help. I'm in a rush!

Comment: Did you check if "date" is defined ?

Answer (score 8):

Try the code below and note when using props and object: **props.expense.date.toLocaleString**

In the course probably missed the **.expense**
Code will work with or without the "?" symbol as **props.expense.date?.toLocaleString** like other post suggest.

---

```
    import "./ExpenseItem.css";

function ExpenseItem(props) {
  const month = props.expense.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  const day = props.expense.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  const year = props.expense.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { year: "numeric" });

  return (
    <div className="expense-item">
      <div>
        <div>{month}</div>
        <div>{day}</div>
        <div>{year}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Comment: Bro. This works. But what is the "?" after date ?

Comment: Babel is a javascript compiler. When you are using it, this "?" is transformed in a javascript validation like { props ? props : "props is not valid"}. When the interrogation is there, it makes this validation in a clean way. You should read more about babel https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')`

in my code

```
      <div className="coin-data">
            <p className="coin-price">Rs.{price}</p>
             <p className="coin-volume">Rs.{volume.toLocaleString()}</p>
            {pricechange<0 ? (
                <p className="coin-percent red">{pricechange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            ):(
                <p className="coin-percent green">{pricechange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            )
        }
        <p className="coin-marketcap">
            Mkt Cap: Rs.{marketcap.toLocaleString()}
        </p>
        </div>
```

In my case using `?` to check the fields having value or not

```
      <div className="coin-data">
            <p className="coin-price">Rs.{price}</p>
             <p className="coin-volume">Rs.{volume?.toLocaleString()}</p>
            {pricechange<0 ? (
                <p className="coin-percent red">{pricechange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            ):(
                <p className="coin-percent green">{pricechange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            )
        }
        <p className="coin-marketcap">
            Mkt Cap: Rs.{marketcap?.toLocaleString()}
        </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, I thought I was crazy I'm literally doing this same react course on the exact same step and I'm trying to figure out wtf I'm doing wrong? I added the ? but now the date doesn't display.

Okay, if you move further ahead he corrects the problem, within the return on the ExpenseItem.js file you need to add the follow:

```
<ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
```

Comment: Yes I found out later in the course. But the explanation about the Props part was a bit confusing. You didn't think so?

Answer (score 1):

> In your child component, you need to add a prop that gets the value of 'date'.
> This way it won't return 'date' as undefined. Check the example below. In ExpenseItem.js add

```
 <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check that you didn't forget to pass the data.

In **ExpenseForm.js** the submitHandler function saves the NewExpense with

```
props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData).
```

It is crucial to pass the expenseData.

Answer (score 0):

You May Have Already Found The Solution To This
but I am also doing the same course and I was stuck in the same part

what I did notice is that it has nothing to do with the date.toLocaleString.

This error occurs because of the way we name our variables in different components
so make sure that all the variables which are taking the input have the same name

in my case
App.js

```
   const dummy = [{ id: "", date : new Date(),title :"Car Gas Fill Up",amount : 24.20,},]
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
<Card  className="expense-item">
 
<ExpenseDate date ={props.date} />
  <div className="expense-item__description">
    <h2>{props.title}</h2>

    <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
  
  </div>
</Card>
```

Expense.js

```
<Card className="expenses">
    <ExpensesFilter
      defaultYear={filterYear}
      changeYear={filterYearChanger}
    />

    {props.items.map((expense,index) => (
      <ExpenseItem
      key ={index}
        title={expense.title}
        amount={expense.amount}
        date={expense.date}
      
      />
    ))}
  </Card>
```

so variable from App.js array object has the same name in another component where they pass info to child components

Answer (score 0):

I follow this course and I fix this, all that you need just updating **date** object to be between **quotations**

```js
  date: new Date("2020, 7, 14")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem at chapter 5 rendering list and I created object in a state, if not, please skip.
I had the same problem like you, but I had already pass the data to the upper components.

```
<ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
```

Then I review my code in `ExpenseForm.js` file, I created the object in the state

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    enteredTitle: '',
    enterAmount: '',
    enteredDate: ''
})
```

Then I double check my `onSubmit` method and add the following code `expenseData` and pass it though the `onSaveExpenseData()`

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const expenseData = {
        title: userInput.enteredTitle,
        amount: userInput.enterAmount,
        date: new Date(userInput.enteredDate)
    }
    props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);
    setUserInput({
        enteredTitle: '',
        enterAmount: '',
        enteredDate: ''
    })
}
```

Finally problem solved. I used to pass the `userInput` directly to the `onSubmit` method and cause a lot of troubles. Good luck!